# Tooltip echo from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm dealing with this problem since 2 days and I haven't found a solution.

Here's the tooltip script that I'm using: http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/

It works fine, I'm able to show data in HTML format, no problem.

But the problem comes when I want to echo a HTML code from a function that was written by me. The output of the function isn't showed in the tooltip, but outside it.

Here's my function:

```
public function showProducts($uId, $wid){

    $sql1 = "SELECT pids FROM wishlists WHERE uid='$uId' AND id='$wid'";
    $q = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
        $dbprods = $data['pids']; 
        $prods = explode(",", $dbprods);
            for($i = 0; $i < count($prods); $i++){
                $id=$prods[$i];
                $q=mysql_query("SELECT * from products where id='$id'");
                while($bd = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
                    echo '<a href="../product.php?id='.$bd['id'].'">'.$bd['name'].'</a><br />';     
                }
            }

        }                   
}
```

If I'm typing `return $bd['id'];`, the tooltip is fine. The problem comes only with that HTML output. The tooltip and function call is this `echo '# <a class="tooltip" title="Products <br />'.$this->showProducts($uid, $wid).'">'.$data['name'].'</a><br />';`

I have also tried to modify the my function into something like

`while($bd = mysql_fetch_array($q)){ ?>
<a href="../product.php?id=<?php echo $bd['id'];?>"><?php echo $bd['name'];?></a><br />
<?php  }`

but still no result. Does anyone helps me out?

Comment: have you checked the generated HTML source? was it valid? was it what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, it's ok if i'm not using it in the tooltip. I kinda think that the problem are the " "...but I dont know how to deal with it. I'm stucked

Comment: does the tooltip work (with a test page *you* generated)? have you included js+css+whateveritneeds? it's either a problem in the PHP code, or in the generated HTML, I doubt it's both..

Comment: As I said, the tooltip works fine as long as I'm not typing ECHO that HTML code. If I type `<strong>blablabla</strong>` for example, it works fine. Or if in my function I type `return 5` or another thing instead of that echo, the tooltip it works fine. The problem comes `only` with that echoed HTML code.

Comment: You are nesting an a tag within another one

Comment: And what should I do?